# Different look of view returned by same action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writting simple web page (kind of blog) and I am blocked with following issue. 
In Views/Shared in _Layout.cshtml I have defined layout of page.

My routing rules looks like that

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
"paging", // Route name
 "Home/GetArticleListForCategory/{id}/{pageNo}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Home", action = "GetArticleListForCategory", id = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNo = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
 "Default", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
  );
```

When I run action  from link 
*http://localhost:3282/Home/GetArticleListForCategory/1*
the page is **displayed properly**

When I run action from link 
*http://localhost:3282/Home/GetArticleListForCategory/1/1*
**the page looks 'raw'** (there is no layout on page, no images etc.) I have compared html returned by pages from two links but they are identical.
Controller action looks like that:

```
public ActionResult GetArticleListForCategory(int id,int pageNo = 1)
{

    int articlesPerPageNo = ConfigurationHelper.NoOfArticlePerPage;
    int totalNoOfArticles;
    List<PostShort> listOfPostforCategory = GetListOfShortArticles(pageNo,articlesPerPageNo ,out totalNoOfArticles);

    int totalPagesNo = (totalNoOfArticles + articlesPerPageNo - 1) / articlesPerPageNo;
    ViewData["PageTotal"] = totalPagesNo;
    ViewData["PageNo"] = pageNo;

    return View("CategoryPosts",listOfPostforCategory);
}
```

Note that parameters are properly passed to action (tested in debug).

Does anybody have idea what is the source of such behaviour and how to solve it ?

Thanks in advace for help.
Best Regards

Comment: I don't think you need this: `id = UrlParameter.Optional` in your first route

Comment: I have checked your suggestion but still same behaviour.

Comment: How many posts are returned from GetListOfShortArticles for each URL?

Comment: Can you post how you're including your stylesheets and images in the page?  When you request `page/1` with a relative location, it might work, but `page/1/1` won't because the relative `../styles/something.css` would need to be `../../styles/something.css` in which case you'd need to use the `Url.Content` html helper.

Comment: How can find out how many posts are returned ?

Comment: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href="../../Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: I probably find what is wrong. In page displayed from first mentioned link the style.css link targets: localhost:3282/Content/style.css  in case of second mentioned link it targets: localhost:3282/Home/Content/style.css  Can you explaing why such thing happens ?

Comment: can you post the code which renders `style.css`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="../../Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

here are my doubts in _layout.cshtml image is declared as follows

```
<img src="../../Content/img02.jpg" width="1000" height="300" alt="" />
```

when such link is used 
**http://localhost:3282/Home/GetArticleListForCategory/1**
the link to one of images looks like that **http://localhost:3282/Content/img02.jpg**
but when I add one more parameter to link:
**http://localhost:3282/Home/GetArticleListForCategory/1/1** 
where first number is category and second is page number whe link to same image looks like that **http://localhost:3282/Home/Content/img02.jpg**

why same action return view located in other place ?

Comment: the problem is with getting image from Content folder, how can I in cshtml target direct (not relative) path to Content folder ?